# Angular service returns value but not displayed in page

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am learning Angular from scratch. I have created a component named 'mylink' and a service for the same.

I tried to return a string value from the service using 'observable, of' and 'subscribe'. The service returns the string, but it is not displayed in webpage. While debugging, in the component, it shows that the data received is 
"Unexpected end of input". No error in console. How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

**mylink.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MylinkService } from '../mylink.service';
import { dashCaseToCamelCase } from '@angular/compiler/src/util';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-link',
  templateUrl: './mylink.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mylink.component.css']
})
export class MylinkComponent implements OnInit {
  myName: String;
  result: any;

  constructor(private mylinkService: MylinkService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getMylinkData();
  }

  getMylinkData(): void {
    this.mylinkService.getMylinkData()
    .subscribe(dataV => this.myName = dataV);
  }
}
```

**mylink.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable()
export class MylinkService {

  private mylinkUrl = 'api/mylink';  // URL to web api

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getMylinkData (): Observable<String> {
    var val = 'From service';
    return of(val);
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>My Link page</h2>

<div>
  <label>My name is:
    <input #myName />
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this :

```
<div>
  <label>My name is:
    <input [(ngModel)]="myName" name="myName" />
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you’re trying to do is something like

```
   <label>My name is:
       {{myName}}
  </label>
```

On the component you are assigning the returned string from the service to the public property myName. If you want to display it in the page you just need to interpolate this value as shown in my example